# Retrieve Mailbox from a deleted user

Tags: exchange

I deleted a user from exchange server 2010 and added the user back how do i get the previous mailbox of the user from exchange server 2010

Answer (score 2):

Reattach old mailbox to new user. It should be visible, still. If not - well, go to your backups. But I think mailboxes are tombstoned by default.

Details are at:

http://exchangeserverpro.com/reconnect-disconnected-mailbox-exchange-server-2010

with picures on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. How do i do that. am a novice in exchange server management

Comment: You ask your admin or you read the doucmentation. I am a strong believer one should read the documentation first before touching business critical systems. Somoene else may chime in, I refuse to help people not knowing what they do and not learning.

Comment: Hello TomTom. it is a test question. Am Studying to become a Server Admin. I have actually googled for solutions without finding one. Am willing to learn

Comment: Good. Accepted - you should have said so.

Comment: The mailbox shohld show up somewhere (damn, last time I did that was half a year ago) as orphaned and the action menu for it should allow you do assign it another AD account. I have updated the answer with a link to a blog post that contains pictures etc.